# Bootstrap Browse to add url in list

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to asking. I have looked around for a few days and didn't find anything. but I have read a lot of great answers here.

**What I have:** I currently have a Bootstrap "website" that is used on a local share. No calls are external. This page or pages are being used to manage files (docx,xlsx,txt,etc) for a quick user interface. The files are accessed thru urls that call files from local folders. All files are stored in folders inside the "website" directory folder.

**What I need:** I am looking for a way to enable the users to be able to use a button to browse and add new files as URL link's to the category lists in the bootstrap site. the category Lists are as shown below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target="#10">Category</button>
                <div id="10" class="collapse">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I'm open to any changes that can be made, but I prefer to keep it as simple as possible for people who might inherit this project also, I would like to keep the formatting/styling. its very useful and it become habit to unskilled users. Also, this will not ever be hosted on a web server. it needs to run from the share. Can this be done with jquery or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Well the basic problem i see in your spec is one thing - you'r having a web app, running locally, and want to access local files... right? I mean, ok you're saying you have URL's pointing to those local files... is there a webserver who delivers those files through HTTP? Or are you going through the file protocoll (file://)?

I see two solutions here:

1. Going with HTTP - would mean, you have to setup a http server just to deliver those files which are found locally... Feels clumpsy and totally overloaded for such a simple task. With this "server" application, acting like an API for your files, you would be aple in PHP or Java or anything to lookup the folder - iterate over all files and maybe in a special URL (localhost/listAllFiles) you would be able to get a list of all files available to dynamically populate your bootstrup ul/li.

Downside: You need a new ServerApp just to serve this API. You need a http server.

2. Using the HTML5 File API. A browser normally has no access at all to a local harddrive (security reasons). But with the now available html5 File API (http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) - you can ask the user of the App to grant access to his drive.

After you have granted access - you can just lookup any folder and his files with simple javascript!

So, i would go with that solution in this simple task...

Leaving the html with an empty ul - on page load, i would get a list of all files with html5 file api - and populate the ul/li dynamically with pure javascript... bam, done! :)

*What you say about keeping the coding-style of bootstrap... this is still given, doesn't matter how you solve it... Populating the ul/li and styling it differently are two different things.. all you are asking here is how you could get the data and render it - but how it is is displayed, this is already given by bootstrap.*

*I mean, you just don't have to add more custom classes to the construct or don't add new dom elements to it.
But with leaving it empty for an initial load and just populating it dynamically by javscript doesn't break this sanity - and must be possible for every bootstrap project ;)*

*One who is not aware of coding is still able to re-style it just by going through the CSS.. And someone like that will never be able to code a solution like "get files from local harddrive and populate dynamically" - this has simply nothing todo with bootstrap itself :)*

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm pretty sure this is the solution. Although I'll have to learn more about html5 in implement it. Thanks again!

Comment: I might has spoke too soon, The html5 file API will not be used by all browsers. I need the solution to be all browsers. But it did help me define my issue better. I want to display a list of files from a local directory and display them in the category lists as urls. Each category, will have its own list of files and they are to be launched by the file:// protocol. Sorry if my first post was unclear. thanks again for any help that can be offered.

Comment: hey no prob - so i thought now.. then you're forced to go with the http server.. but wait - i see there are plenty of polyfills available for html5 file api.. even with silverlight lol :D https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills